# stubbing process.nextTick to relay arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, sinon

For better or worse we stub `process.nextTick` to call its first argument (the callback) **synchronously**. Behold the code:

```
global.test_clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
sinon.stub(process, 'nextTick').callsArg(0);
```

However `process.nextTick` [takes a function and an arbitrary set of arguments](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args]) to pass to that function. The above code drops those extra arguments.

Can a Sinon sage advise how I can call arg 0 (the callback) with the remaining arguments as arguments to the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
sinon.stub(process, 'nextTick').callsFake((fn, ...args) => fn(...args));
```